# Mongo: weird max object size error

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm running mongo java driver 2.11.0 and I run into this issue :

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBObject of size 5239290 is over Max BSON size 16777216
```

As you can see the error message is wrong: my object 5239290 is less than 16777216.

Reading the mongodb java driver code I can see the following lines ( com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(BSONObject) ):

```java
if (objectSize > Math.max(_mongo.getConnector().getMaxBsonObjectSize(), Bytes.MAX_OBJECT_SIZE)) {
    throw new MongoInternalException("DBObject of size " + objectSize + " is over Max BSON size " + _mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize());
}
```

The reason for this strange error is that _mongo.getConnector().getMaxBsonObjectSize() returns a different value from _mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize().

Do you have any clue to explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: The maximum object size is determined by the database version. Very old versions of MongoDB have limits of only 4MB. It seems `_mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize()` is using a cached value or a different value from the one given by `getConnector().get...`. Are you using a very old MongoDB version? In any case, that's a driver bug because the error message doesn't use the value it used in the comparison which is simply wrong. The driver should store the result of `Math.max` in a variable and reuse that.

Comment: Thanks, I agree concerning the driver bug. It appears that the server (v2.6.3) was in an unconsistent state : configured with replicaSet then moved back to standalone. Fixing server config with a server restart solved the issue. I have no idea why this var (max bson size) was affected by this bad server state. Anyway thanks for for your support.